# Can you install java libraries like built-in libraries

Tags: java, classpath

I've been learning java and I like the syntax and the control flow. However, when it comes to installing and using libraries I find it kind of cluttered.

I'm using IntelliJ and I'm following along with the book *Computer Science: An Interdisciplinary Approach* by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne. Towards the end of the first chapter it starts using a free library from the website called stdlib.jar. I successfully got the library working in my IDE and ran into issues trying to run the code in the terminal.

After some light googling I discovered using the -classpath modifier when compiling and running in the terminal:

```
>javac -classpath ".\path\to\library.jar;" MyCode.java
>java -classpath ".\path\to\library.jar;" MyCode
```

I'm very familiar with creating and using packages with Python, and understand that Python was meant to be high level, but this syntax just seems clunky. For example, if I compile the code with a certain dependency, why do I still need to reference that code when I run it?

Is there any way to just install a library that I will always want to have access to the same as java's built-in libraries?

I'm probably being a lowly python coder and completely missing the point of the process, but any info would be helpful.

Comment: you should try a dependency management tool, like maven or gradle

Comment: *"For example, if I compile the code with a certain dependency, why do I still need to reference that code when I run it?"* - depends on how you compile and bundle the jar. Some jars contain all their dependencies.

Comment: While there is a way to add libraries so they will be available as extensions, they will be available for **all** calls to javac and java. That can cause unexpected errors. For instance, I've encountered an example where Bouncy Castle was installed like that, and it conflicted with versions needed and provided by applications. I will therefore not explain how to do it; the problems will outweigh the advantages.

Comment: @RobSpoor The ext-folder mechanism was removed in Java 9 (maybe even Java 8).

Comment: You can build a JAR that references the libraries in its manifest, and then you just run the JAR with `java -jar <name-of-the-jar>`, or you can build a so-called fat-jar (a.k.a. uber-jar) which contains all classes.

Comment: As @Stultuske suggests: you are running into a solved problem. That's what Java build systems with their dependency management are built for. Use Maven or Gradle (personally I suggest Gradle, but it's somewhat subjective). And if you want, you can even tell those tools to build an uber-jar that contains all required classes, including those from dependencies.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel all the better!